# How to delete duplicates in table1 based match in table2 in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, duplicates

I looked into google and stackoverflow question and answers to find the solution to my query.
Did not find exact answer.

Looking to delete duplicates in table1 based on match in table2 data.
table1 ColumnA URL(columnA) and same in table2 ColumnA(Links)
I run this query to delete it however it taking hours of time to delete the duplicates not even displaying results.
table1 has 8+ million rows and table2 has close to 4 million rows.

```html
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE Urls NOT IN (
  SELECT Urls FROM table1 
  EXCEPT 
  SELECT Links FROM table2
)
```

where I been wrong with code. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Not hugely familiar with SQLITE, but try:

```
Delete from table1 as x
Where EXISTS (
  Select Links from table2 y
  Where y.Links=x.Urls
)
```

If your two tables are actually spreadsheets this is still going to be slow but this is a little more straightforward than what you coded.

Comment: Execution finished with errors.
Result: near "x": syntax error
At line 1:
Delete from table1 x

Comment: @shansyed add `as`: `Delete from table1 as x`. This is SQLite's peculiarity.

Comment: its taking long hours to process the data

Comment: any better way to process the data.  I do not see any other tool efficient than sqlite